Running chromium on Rpi5 using Yocto
I have a Raspberry Pi 5. I want to get chromium to run on it. I want to build Linux via Yocto.
I'm using the Kirkstone branch of Yocto.
My local.conf relating to chromium
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " xserver-xorg xf86-video-fbdev xf86-input-evdev glew freeglut"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " kbd chromium-x11 xkeyboard-config-locale-en-gb"

IMAGE_FEATURES:append = " hwcodecs x11 x11-base"

DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " opengl x11 systemd pam"

VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units"

I build with the command
bitbake core-image-minimal

The build completes and linux boots on the pi, but when I try to run chromium with chromium --no-sandbox I get the following errors:
[564:564:0423/091944.756707:ERROR:policy_logger.cc(157)] :components/enterprise/browser/controller/chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(163) Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[564:564:0423/091944.871246:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[564:564:0423/091944.910644:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[564:564:0423/091944.932636:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[564:564:0423/091944.956266:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[564:564:0423/091944.991144:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[564:564:0423/091945.011115:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[564:564:0423/091945.036033:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[564:564:0423/091945.057275:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[564:564:0423/091945.085960:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(990)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=11
[564:564:0423/091945.086092:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(448)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Complete stab in the dark: could chromium be defaulting to GPU hardware acceleration and that isn't supported by the hardware? Maybe there's a relevant compile flag?

I'll see if I can find what flags are being used.
